# Windows 10 pro importing certificate through command line create a duplicate store

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, ssl-certificate, certutil

I am trying to import a certificate into my "Local computer" account under "Personal" certificate store. 
Though when running one of the below 2 commands, the certificate is imported into a new certificate store called also Personal.
First command:

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\LabCert.cer" -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\LocalMachine\Personal' -Verbose
```

Second command:

```
CertUtil -v -addstore "Personal" "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\LabCert.cer"
```

Can someone please advise how can I import my certificate into the original Personal store?
Thanks

Comment: Should not it be `My` store?

Comment: Try importing into the "My" store

Comment: You are both right. Thank you:) Just changed the "Personal" to "My" and that solved the problem.